# Can we create a simple thesaurus from a field in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, nlp, nltk

I am trying to find synonyms and antonyms for one word, using strings from a field in a dataframe and not a standard wordnet.synsets lexical database.  I'm pretty sure this is possible, but I'm not sure how to feed in the appropriate data source (my specific field).

For instance, the code below works fine.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet   #Import wordnet from the NLTK
syn = list()
ant = list()
for synset in wordnet.synsets("fake"):
   for lemma in synset.lemmas():
      syn.append(lemma.name())    #add the synonyms
      if lemma.antonyms():    #When antonyms are available, add them into the list
          ant.append(lemma.antonyms()[0].name())
print('Synonyms: ' + str(syn))
print('Antonyms: ' + str(ant))
```

I tried to convert the field to an array, and use that...

```
import pandas  as pd
import nltk.corpus
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\my_path\\dataset.csv")
df['review_text'] = df['review_text'].astype(str)
type(df)
df.dtypes

asarray = pd.array(df['review_text'])

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet   #Import wordnet from the NLTK
syn = list()
ant = list()
for synset in wordnet.asarray('fake'):
   for lemma in df['review_text'].iterrows():
      syn.append(lemma.name())    #add the synonyms
      if lemma.antonyms():        #When antonyms are available, add them into the list
          ant.append(lemma.antonyms()[0].name())
print('Synonyms: ' + str(syn))
print('Antonyms: ' + str(ant))
```

When I run that, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'asarray'
```

The field in the dataframe looks like this:

```
feels comfortable i wear day!
package came end missing box. since itâ€™s gift i update actual fit.
birkenstock amazing shoe!!!! i wish i ten pairs!
delivered advertised.... shoe looks & fits expected. leather color seems bit lighter one seen store, still satisfactory.
second pair i had. nothing beats them.
```

These are the first 5 rows.  Maybe the issue is related to this thing (not sure):  `itâ€™s`

Comment: Can you show top first lines of `dataset.csv`?

Comment: The field that I am feeding in looks like this: 

feels comfortable i wear day!
package came end missing box. since itâ€™s gift i update actual fit.
birkenstock amazing shoe!!!! i wish i ten pairs!
delivered advertised.... shoe looks & fits expected. leather color seems bit lighter one seen store, still satisfactory.
second pair i had. nothing beats them.
they totally fake ðŸ˜¡. they felt weird i finally noticed â€œmade germanyâ€ logo above. they also smell like glue leather. infuriating happen!

Comment: Put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo or something.

Error happens on:

```
for synset in wordnet.asarray('fake'):
```

Where wordnet is an object from `nltk.corpus`, thus a `WordNetCorpusReader`

And before the for loop, you have

```
asarray = pd.array(df['review_text'])
```

that reads in a Pandas array/series into the `asarray` variable. But it's not related to `WordNetCorpusReader`

Comment: I just commented out the 'asarray = pd.array(df['review_text'])'.  You are right, I'm getting an error on this 'for synset in wordnet.asarray('fake'):'.  Error message is 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'.  How can I make this work?  Thanks.

Comment: This seems to work for me:

my_list = []
my_list = df['review_text'].values.tolist()

s = ','.join(str(v) for v in my_list)

type(s)